# Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener in MainActivity instead of Fragment

Tags: java, android

I would like to check in my `MainActivity` class if a `Switch` in the `Fragment` has been changed. So right now i have a `Fragment` class and a Main class (`ActivityName`).

I've already tried to get the reference out of the Fragment to my Main Activity Class but thats not working because of i don't know when to call it (it says always null reference I guess it's because of onviewcreated hasn't been called if i try that).

I am able to create the `Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener` in my Fragment but not in the Main Class.
(Looks like this)

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        switchA = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.switchA);

        switchA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){

                }
                else{

                }
            }
        });
```

so whats the best choice to get that Information out of my Fragment class to my activity class?

I am thankful for any advice :)

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use an interface between activity and fragment. By interface you can call back the activity from fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't touch Fragment's views from Activity. The best way to tackle your issue is to create special interface to provide interaction between Fragment and Activity, for example:

ChackedChangedCallback.java:

```
public interface CheckedChangeCallback() {
    void onCheckedChanged(boolean isChecked);
}
```

in fragment:

```
private CheckedChangeCallback callback = null;

public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof CheckedChangeCallback) {
        this.callback = (CheckedChangeCallback) activity;
    }
}

public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    callback = null;
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        switchA = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.switchA);

        switchA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                callback.onCheckedChange(isChecked);
            }
        });
```

In activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CheckedChangeCallback {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChange(boolean isChecked) {
        // do stuff here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A fast solution would be to create a function in Main that handles the checked status of the Switch. Then in your fragment, you can call that function to handle the Switch click using getActivity().functionName()
So you would have in your main for example:

```
public void handleSwitchClick(boolean checked) {
   if (checked) {
      // do something
   else {
      // do something else
   }
}
```

and in the fragment:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    switchA = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.switchA);

    switchA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              getActivity().handleSwitchClick(isChecked);
        }
    });
```

Don't go the other way around however as you shouldn't be accessing fragment instances from your Main Activity.

If you need to constantly check the status of the switch in Main, you can define a new member to account for whether it's checked or not so you would have:

```
private boolean switchChecked = false;

public void handleSwitchClick(boolean checked) {
   if (checked) {
      switchChecked = true;
      // do something
   else {
     switchChecked = false;
      // do something else
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that fast reply but i've chosen the Interface "guide" as solution, have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

In your `Activity`

```
static ActivityName activity;
```

in   `onCreate` method of `Activity`

```
activity = this;
```

Now create a method in your `Activity`

```
public static ActivityName getInstance()
{
      return activity;
}
```

Now create method for handelling `Switch` method in your `Activity` (Main class)

```
public void handleSwitch(boolean value)
{
       if(value)
       {
          .....
       }
       else
       {
           ......
        }
}
```

Now in `Fragment`

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    switchA = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.switchA);

    switchA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


            ActivityName.getInstance().handleSwitch(isChecked);


            if(isChecked){

            }
            else{

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should never store Activity in static field (memory leak).

Comment: wow that was fast, thanks a lot but i've chosen the Interface solution, anywayws have a nice day :)